# Can't connect to any Apple related services via home network

Tags: network, dns

I own an iPhone 5 and a 12-inch iPad Pro and I ran into this weird problem today where I was unable to reach any Apple related services via my home network. I was suddenly unable to connect to the App Store with both of my devices both via Wi-Fi when everything was just fine yesterday. It wasn't like my Internet's down or anything - I can go to any other sites just fine, and all of my games that need to be online didn't run into any problems, and I don't think anything has changed about my router settings either.

The first thing I checked was if App Store was down - unlikely, but possible - so I switched over to my phone's cellular network, and it connected to the App Store no problem. I was able to reach the store with my iPad through my phones network too.

I decided that my network is just acting weird, and with my iPad I consulted Google for an answer. That led me to, unsurprisingly, the Apple support site, which I was unable to open. So I tried again with my computer, which is connected to the router via Ethernet. That, too, failed, but at least Chrome gave me a better idea of what the problem is, which apparently had to do with apple's DNS address. I did the only thing I knew how, and that is to clear the DNS cache, which sadly did not work either.

At this point, I am both confused and out of ideas. I would like to ask if anyone can give me some insight. What is happening, why is it happening, and is there anything I can do to fix it, or is it something I can just wait out?

Comment: Seems like the same issue I'm having on one Mac - see [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/267968/168832) for which I don't yet have an answer. I intend to shortly update it and add a bounty. In my case, whenever it happens, it seems to rectify itself after quite some hours and during that period Google Chrome is the only browser capable of accessing any Apple web content.  I _think_ I've narrowed the problem down somewhat to this iMac sometimes being given an IP address already being used on the network, so I will probably manually allocate it a static IP address as a test.